# Loop closure returning function instead of string

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to create a closure in my for loop, how ever, it keeps returning a function instead of a string.

```
$(function() {
    var addID = function(id) {
        var temp = id;
        return function() {
            return "http://localhost:3000/board/raptrex/" + temp;
        }
    };

    $.get("http://localhost:3000/board/raptrex", function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
        var $deleteUL = $('#delete');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var url = addID(data[i]._id);

            console.log(url);

            var $item = $('<li></li>').text(data[i].name).click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                  type: "DELETE",
                  url: url
                })
                  .done(function( msg ) {
                    alert( "Deleted: " + msg );
                  });
            });
            $deleteUL.append($item);
        }
    }); 
});
```

This returns `http://localhost:3000/function%20()%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22http://localhost:3000/board/raptrex/%22%20+%20temp;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20}` when I click on my li element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a function instead of a string with `addID`. Try the following:

```
var addID = function(id) {
    var temp = id;
    return "http://localhost:3000/board/raptrex/" + temp;
};
```

Comment: This is correct. Side question, when I click listener is fired, the url is always the last one, how would I fix that?

Comment: Right, I don't see that! Put the `var url = addID(data[i]._id);` inside the listener function and before the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: I cant as data[i]._id becomes undefined when you click on it

Comment: Right. I don't know how is your DOM but you can try to put the `var url = addID(data[$(this).index()]._id);` inside the listener. If all your `<li></li>` are in the same level and you don't have more `<li>` items in your document, this should work for you.